# Is it possible to make use of 2nd level cache when querying foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, infinispan

afaik entities are indexed just by their primary key in the 2nd level cache, so querying related entities won't make use of it:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Phone> phones;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;    
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
    private Employee owner;
    ...
}

EntityManager em;

// uses 2nd level cache
Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1); 

// doesn't use 2nd level cache. Even if 2nd level cache actually 
// contains all referenced phones, there will be a DB call.
employee.getPhones();
```

Is it possible to avoid the db call, when accessing phones and make use of the 2nd level cache? Is there a cache implementation supporting custom indexing?

I'm currently using wildfly 14 with hibernate/infinispan.

Will accessing phones at least make use of query cache or just `em.createQuery(...)`?

Comment: If the JPA provider has cached the "id"s of the related `Phone`s in the L2 cache entry for the `Employee` then it should not need to go to the database. It gets the L2 cache entry for the `Employee`, and then looks up the L2 cache entries for the related ids. The JPA provider I use (not Hibernate) does that.

Comment: Which JPA provider do you use? Next to infinispan i already tried ehcache and it's the same behavior.

Comment: I use DataNucleus. Using some different L2 cache is not the issue ... the JPA provider decides what goes in the L2 cache and when it is accessed. Perhaps look at what your JPA provider is storing in the L2 cache, and maybe they have an option to store relations too if not already done?

Comment: Is there a common configuration specified by JPA to enable such behavior? Or in Hibernate? I can't change to another provider.

Comment: Cache providers, such as Infinispan, treat entities as black objects, so we don't normally try to dehydrate entities to further cache things... If you want to try things in a smaller scale, you can modify [this Infinispan + Hibernate simple tutorial](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/hibernate-cache/local/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/hibernate/cache/local/InfinispanHibernateCacheLocal.java) with your data model and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. There is a collection cache in Hibernate which has to be explicitly enabled by annotating the collection with `org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private long id;
    ...
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Phone> phones;
    ...
}
```

It works perfectly!